# Adding onclick function to div in Angular directive link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have an angular directive with a link scope.

In that scope, I append a div. I would like to add an event listener to this div.

When I do so, the event listener is overridden by the ng-click native attributes of the directive.

What is the best way forward? Trying to use element to identify the element does not work as element compiles asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use ng-click?

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.onHandleClick = function() {
        console.log('onHandleClick');
    };
}
```

---

```
<div ng-click="onHandleClick($event)"/>
```

Comment: Because it's a child element within the div appended within the link scope.

Comment: It should still have visibility of this link scope.

Comment: $compile('<div class="childElement" ng-click="onHandleClick($event)">')(scope)

Comment: when I try your original post, the scope.onHandleClick function is not called; nothing happens.

Comment: Can we see your code where you create and append the div?